# Getting No JSON object could be decoded while using simplejson

Tags: python, urllib

I'm accessing some data via an API.

The following is my code snippet:

```
url = self.base_url + specific_url + "?q=" + str(query) + "&" + "filters=[[%22category_id%22,[" + category_id + "]]]" + "&start=" + start + "&sortby=[[%22mpn%22, %22asc%22]]" + "&limit=" + limit + "&apikey=" + self.api_key
response_json = self.web_fetch(url)
return simplejson.loads(urllib.unquote(response_json))
```

When I go to the URL directly, I can see the data fine. But in my code 'm getting the following error:

```
No JSON object could be decoded
```

I started getting this error when I added `&sortby=[[%22mpn%22, %22asc%22]]` to the url but I am able to navigate to the page fine in my browser so not sure if that's causing the problem or not.

What would cause this error and what are things I can try to fix it?

Comment: When you go to the page in your browser, do you see json? Are you sure there are no extraneous characters? Also, have you looked at the raw response you receive?

Answer (score 1):

"No JSON object could be decoded" usually means your JSON is an empty string.  Print the value of `response_json` to see it.  Remember the first rule of debugging: When in Doubt, Print More Out.

Comment: You're right, the JSON response is blank... but that's weird because when I go that URL in a browser, it produces a response.

Comment: It's possible that the site doesn't like your user agent. You're probably using a default user agent, if so try setting it to something meaningful.

Comment: Where would I do that? in the `web_fetch`?

Comment: `def web_fetch(self, url):
        buffer = StringIO()
        curl = pycurl.Curl()
        curl.setopt(curl.URL, url)
        curl.setopt(curl.TIMEOUT, self.timeout)
        curl.setopt(curl.WRITEFUNCTION, buffer.write)
        curl.perform()
        curl.close()
        response = buffer.getvalue().strip()
        return response`

Comment: I added the following but no luck...         `curl.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, ['User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0'])
        curl.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, ['Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'])`

Comment: Unfortunately, there are all sorts of things different about the browser's request and your request, and the site can decide to serve different response for any reason at all.